# Average Calculating Program Issue

Tags: java

I've just started learning Java, and I'm pretty confused at this point. I'm trying to make a program that will average out any amount of numbers that the user would input, but I can't figure out how to allow the user to input as many numbers as they want. Right now, the code just lets them do 1 number before it averages.

Notes:
There's a good chance I'm writing this totally wrong, I'm doing this to see what I know so far

I use Eclipse

I'm learning from www.thenewboston.org

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Enter Grades Now");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double input2 = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println(average(input2));
    }

    public static double average(double...numbers){
        double total=0;
        for(double x:numbers)
            total+=x;

        return total/numbers.length;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `LinkedList<Double>` and a loop to let the user input an artificial amount of numbers.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
List<Double> allDoubles = new LinkedList<Double>();

do {
    System.out.print("Next grade: ");
    allDoubles.add(input.nextDouble());
} while (input.hasNextDouble());

System.out.println(average(allDoubles.toArray(new Double[0])));
```

Enter as many values as you like and then enter some text like `"done"`.

Answer (score 1):

You need a loop to take in all of the values. A `List` to store them is helpful too:

```
  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Enter Grades Now:");

    List<Double> inputs =  new ArrayList<Double>();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(input.hasNextDouble()){

          inputs.add(input.nextDouble()); //add values to the list

     }

    }

    System.out.println(average(inputs));
}


 public static double average(List<Double> numbers){
    double total=0;
    for(Double x:numbers)
        total+=x;

    return total/numbers.size();
}
```

Comment: I tried this but The "System.out.println(average(inputs.toArray()));" part said for average: "Return Type For The Method Is Missing", and for inputs: inputs cannot be resolved. It's probably obvious how to fix but like I said I'm a newb :D

Comment: I think I'm missing something, it's still not working for me :/ I may have to put this off for a while until I understand things better

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<Double> al = new ArrayList<Double>();
while(input.hasNextDouble){
    al.add(input.nextDouble())
    System.out.print("Prompt: "); //ask for input here
}
// average the elements in the arraylist
```

Comment: if they don't input a double, it exits

Comment: I could make the input prompt nicer though.

Answer (score 1):

You could suggest user to input numbers, separating them with spaces:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String userInput = input.nextline();

// e.g. "12 23 34"
String[] stringArray = userInput.split(" ");
Double[] doubleArray = new Double[stringArray.length];

// converting string array to double array    
for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; ++) {
    doubleArray[i] = Double.parseDouble(stringArray[i]);
}
System.out.println(average(doubleArray));
```